# Is this robot-programming puzzle solvable?

Tags: logical-deduction

I have gotten into solving this kind of puzzle recently. I've found this one and after an hour of trying, I don't seem to be able to find a solution. I'm starting to think there might be an error and it isn't actually solvable.

[image: Robot-programming puzzle]

This is the site where you can "play" with the puzzle. https://turing.gausshq.com/puzzles/59.c1a5c35e3ffe02c5a1f3

**If it is solvable. These are my suspicions so far:**

1. > There is at least one color-change in the solution.
2. > All changes in direction are counter-clockwise.
3. > The solution follows this path https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYzuI.jpg

**The instructions on the site are a bit vague:**

> Your goal is to create a series of commands that will make the
>   triangle visit all the colored squares in one go without falling on
>   any of the grey ones.

You have to "program" the triangle to move around. You have limited commands (6 in this case).

- The arrows make it move forward or rotate 90º and the Xs change the
  color of the square the triangle is on.
- The colors work like
  conditionals--colored commands are only executed if the triangle is
  in a square of the same color.
- F0 makes the sequence start over.

If you find a solution some hints would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That was quite tricky. Your idea for the path was almost correct.

Some hints if you want to try on your own:

> You have to use F0 twice!

and

> No color change needed!

The solution:

> [image: Turing Program]
>  Its quite straightforward.
>  The base cycle pattern (Left, Forward, Forward) is interrupted with a blue forward and the green restart to account for the modified cycles.
>  So, yes. Its solvable.